# FASM DLL issues in PE64

Tags: assembly, dll, import, proc, fasm

I have these two programs, originally these two ran independently, but I want to include the code from the second in the first.

I tried to export the label, made the label a proc, specified the format to a DLL, but nothing seems to work for me.

I have dug through a lot of information, as well from the fasm specification itself as a lot of others, but not everything tells me to do the same thing and I have tried a few combinations of each of the things but that didn't help.

Can someone point out what's wrong with the below code?
It assembles fine, when I do not use anything that was imported from the second source it also runs fine. When I do though, the program returns error 0xc000007b, even before execution!

This is the first file

```
format PE64

include 'win64a.inc'
;include 'printInt.asm'

entry start

section '.code' code readable executable
start:
    ;call [newline] ;errors

    mov rcx, 317
    mov rdx, 16
    call fromBase10
    mov rcx, rax
    mov r12, rax
    call printArray

    invoke ExitProcess, 0

fromBase10:
    ;rcx -> number
    ;rdx -> base
    mov rax, rcx
    mov r8, rdx
    xor rcx, rcx
    xor rdx, rdx
    .l1:
        inc rcx
        div r8
        push rdx
        xor rdx, rdx
        cmp rax, 0
        jne .l1
    shl rcx, 3
    mov rax, rcx
    add rsp, rcx
    ;stack <- number
    ;rax (, rcx) <- length (bytes)
    ret

toBase10:
    ;rcx -> length (bytes)
    ;rdx -> base
    ;stack -> number
    sub rsp, 8
    mov r8, 1
    xor r9, r9
    mov r10, rdx
    mov r11, rcx
    shr rcx, 3
    .l1:
        mov rax, [rsp]
        sub rsp, 8
        mul r8
        add r9, rax
        mov rax, r8
        mul r10
        mov r8, rax
        dec rcx
        jnz .l1
    add rsp, r11
    add rsp, 8
    mov rax, r9
    ;rax <- number
    ret

printArray:
    ;rcx -> length (bytes)
    ;stack -> array
    sub rsp, rcx
    push r12
    push r13
    add rsp, 16
    mov r13, rcx
    mov r13, rcx
    shr rcx, 3
    mov r12, rcx
    .l1:
        pop rcx
        add rcx, 0x30
        sub rsp, r13    ;ugly, UGLY!!!! :(
        sub rsp, 8
        sub rsp, 32
        call [putchar]
        mov rcx, 0x20
        call [putchar]
        add rsp, 32
        add rsp, 8
        add rsp, r13
        dec r12
        jnz .l1
    sub rsp, r13
    sub rsp, 16
    mov rax, r13
    pop r13
    pop r12
    add rsp, rax
    ;stack <- array
    ret

section '.idata' import data readable writeable
library kernel, 'kernel32.dll',\
    msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll',\
    printLib, 'printLib.dll'

import kernel, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
import msvcrt, printf, 'printf',\
    putchar, 'putchar'
import printLib, printInt, 'printInt',\
    newline, 'newline'
```

and this is the second:

```
format PE64 DLL

entry DllMain

include 'win64a.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable

proc DllMain hinstDLL, fdwReason, lpvReserved
    mov rax, TRUE
    ret
endp

proc printInt integer
    push r10
    push r11
    push r12
    push r13
    push r14
    mov rcx, [integer]
    sub rsp, 32

    mov r12, rcx
    mov r13, 10
    xor r14, r14

    test r12, r12
    jns .e1
        neg r12
        mov rcx, 45
        call [putchar]    
    .e1:

    .l1:
        mov rax, r12
        mov rdx, 0
        div r13

        mov rcx, rdx
        add rcx, 0x30
        mov r12, rax
        push rcx
        inc r14
        test r12, r12
        jnz .l1

    mov r12, r14    
    .l2:
        pop rcx
        sub rsp, 32
        call [putchar]
        add rsp, 32
        dec r14
        jnz .l2

    add rsp, 32
    pop r14
    pop r13
    pop r12
    pop r11
    pop r10
    ret
endp

proc newline
   sub rsp, 32
   mov rcx, 0xa
   call [putchar]
   mov rcx, 0xd
   call [putchar]
   add rsp, 32
   ret
endp

;rdtsc64x:
;   rdtsc
;   shl rdx, 32
;   add rax, rdx
;   mov rdx, 0
;ret

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

library msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'

import msvcrt, printf, 'printf',\
    putchar, 'putchar'

section '.edata' data readable
export 'printInt.dll',\
    printInt, 'printInt',\
    newline, 'newline'

data fixups
end data
```

I'm absolutely clueless as to why this doesn't work, all help would be much appreciated.
Another thing that's confusing me is that if I define a procedure in the first file it doesn't want to assemble, could someone point out why that is?

Something I'd also like to hear is if the way I'm returning an array is absolutely the wrong way of returning something that looks like an array and how that should be done.